# Creating a multidimensional-array in JSON from CSV files

Tags: json, csv, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a JSON file from multiple CSV files. The files would be named like bugs.csv and executions.csv.

Example of the bugs.csv files:

```
month,,1,2,3,4
app1,ownerA,42,34,38,12
app2,ownerA,13,23,24,43
app3,ownerB,48,72,39,62
```

Example of the executions.csv files:

```
month,,1,2,3,4
app1,ownerA,1200,1500,900,1000
app2,ownerA,600,650,660,540
app3,ownerB,2750,3500,3000,3200
```

What I would like the JSON to look like:

```
[{"Application":"app1",
"Owner":"ownerA",
"bugs":[[1,42],[2,34],[3,38],[4,12]],
"executions":[[1,1200],[2,1500],[3,900],[4,1000]]},

{"Application":"app2":,
"Owner":"ownerA",
"bugs": [[1,13],[2,23],[3,24],[4,43]],
"executions":[[1,600],[2,650],[3,660],[4,540]]}]
```

Comment: a python script using the csv and json modules could do this for you in a few lines. or you may get lucky and someone more karma-hungry will write it for you.

Comment: Thanks philo.  Does anyone one else have suggestions using javascript?  All of the rest of the work is in javascript and our service provider doesn't have python devs.

Comment: you can also use OpenRefine with a custom JSON export. However OpenRefine doesn't support automation. It will good for a one time job only.

Comment: You can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332450/how-to-save-a-multidimensional-json-array-to-a-csv-file-on-android

Comment: Thanks magdmartin, that did the trick.

Comment: @ecfitzgerald if you could post your solution as an answer to this question, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I used OpenRefine, once you create a project, it let me convert excel files one one layout to the desired JSON layout without needing to re-code each time.  It's a bit manual, but I only do this once a month, so 2-3 minutes doesn't kill me.