# How to manage a (big) JSON object and save the data into the phone?

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite, jackson

I'm working on an App for Android and I have to retreive information (JSON) from a URL; save it on the phone and then display the information on a list.

Until now I've managed to retreive the information using Jackson library, but now I wonder which is the best way to keep this information on the phone.

I tried to save it as a file into the Internal Storage but then, when I try to read this file to create a JSON Object again, I get errors and I can't find the file on the phone using ADB Monitor to check what's going on.

Then, I tried to saved into the External Storage, but with Android 6.0 there is new Permission Model which I don't quite understand. I would like to have more time to just implement this but I have a deadline for this task.

My last option is to create a SQLite database. Which I haven't done before and also is taking some time to understand.

I would like to read some recomendations from people with experience because I'm new on Android and I don't know in which of these options to focus.

Comment: It may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/9460267/1443888

Comment: how big is the json?

Comment: By big do you mean its huge by number of lines or file size?

Comment: The JSON is about 6k objects

Comment: and how many objects are you getting?

Comment: Hi @Tasos, I saved the whole Json into a List<Placemark>, this is done in an Async task. But I need to find a way to persist this data. An access to it even offline. All I have until now, is a List<Placemark> that I've generated using Jackson in my AsyncTask

Comment: check dbflow and GSON sample https://github.com/amorenew/WeatherForecast

Comment: more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39635749/convert-string-to-json-and-getting-error-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to/39636416#39636416

Comment: if you want an instant working solution, you can save your JSON data in `SharedPreferences`. Check though its storage capacity as it is not meant to save big data. But it I recommend you use database to save on your phone.

Comment: you could Convert the data to a CSV file and save it to a folder -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332450/how-to-save-a-multidimensional-json-array-to-a-csv-file-on-android

Comment: If you're going to save a file no need to convert back and forth between CSV and JSON, just save the JSON in a text file.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I honestly thought that saving the JSON in a file would be the easiest way. But I encountered two errors while doing this.
1. Internal storage: Can't access the file once is saved. When I tried to parse it to get back my JSON object, I got a parsing error in the first line.
2. External storage: New permission model in Android 6.0 too complicated and I have no time (Learn this would be ideal).